# Getting hashtable value through passing the keyvalue in C#

Tags: c#, hashtable

I am trying to store and get some values from Hashtable. when i getting the value by passing key to that hashtable it return an null. But that has table having that passed value as key.

I am adding the Hashtable key and value using some string variables.

**EDIT:**
Here is my code.

```
Hashtable hashtbl = new Hashtable();
string[,] ValueArray =new string[3,2];
 ValueArray[0,0]="key1";
 ValueArray[0,1]="value1";
 ValueArray[1,0]="key2";
 ValueArray[1,1]="value2";
 ValueArray[2,0]="key3";
 ValueArray[2,1]="value3";

 for(int i=0;i<ValueArray.GetUpperBound(0);i++)
 {
     string mykey=ValueArray[i,0];
     string myval=ValueArray[i,1];
 if (hashtbl.ContainsKey(mykey)==false)
     {
   hashtbl.Add(mykey,myval);
     }
   }
```

After that i am trying to get those values like

```
string newVal =hashtbl[mykey].ToString();
```

its throws an null exception.

Comment: show the code where you are assigning the HashTable hashtbl field values..

Comment: if the code you posted was all that was modifying hashtbl, and myval was not null when you added it, then retrieving hashtbl[mykey] would not return a null value. There is other code executing somewhere that is modifying something.

Comment: what is the type of `mykey` and value of `myval`?

Comment: i am adding through an array..

Comment: Code seems OK. Try to 'Trim' the key and value strings while inserting and checking in the hash table.

Comment: This is not true, I guess: `string newVal =hashtbl[mykey].ToString();
 - is giving null value`. It throws `NullObjectReference`, right?

Comment: @Zdeslav Vojkovic yes,ur right. its throws an exception only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few possibilities:

- you have already inserted `null` under the `mykey` before and now you are getting it back since `if` statement returns `true`
- `myval` is null and your code works flawlessly
- `mykey` is of type which has a very strange implementation of `GetHashCode`

The first 2 options are not actually possible, as `hashtbl[mykey].ToString()` would throw `NullObjectReference`. I would also assume that this is not the real code as I can't think of a scenario where `x.ToString()` would return null, unless you forgot to mention that `myval`  is of your custom type which overrides it in a strange way.

Therefore, I would assume the latter: `myval` is your type which overrides `ToString` in a way that it returns `null`.

EDIT:
after showing your code and clarifying that the last line doesn't return null but instead throws, it looks like the second scenario is happening. If you run your code through debugger, you will see that you are inserting null values for each entry where key index is > 2. Therefore, hashtable returns null.

This snippet is suspicious: `ValueArray.GetUpperBound(0) - 1`. Try removing '-1'.

Answer (score 0):

I have executed following code and it works fine on my side. Please check whether you are giving `myKey` as an index in the `hasttbl`. myKey should the the sctual string key which you have entered in hashtbl.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Hashtable hashtbl = new Hashtable();
            string[,] ValueArray = new string[10, 2];
            ValueArray[0, 0] = "key1";
            ValueArray[0, 1] = "value1";
            ValueArray[1, 0] = "key2";
            ValueArray[1, 1] = "value2";
            ValueArray[2, 0] = "key3";
            ValueArray[2, 1] = "value3";

            for (int i = 0; i < ValueArray.GetUpperBound(0) - 1;i++)
            {
                if (ValueArray[i, 0] == null)
                    continue;

                string mykey = ValueArray[i, 0];
                string myval = ValueArray[i, 1];
                if (hashtbl.ContainsKey(mykey) == false)
                {
                    hashtbl.Add(mykey, myval);
                }
            }

            foreach (string key in hashtbl.Keys)
            {
                string newVal = hashtbl[key].ToString();

                Console.WriteLine("New value: " + newVal);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Output

```
New value: value2 
New value: value3 
New value: value1
```

Comment: thanks for ur rply.. But i don't want loop throgh all the keys.